# Report Builder 3.0 Sum and Subtract Aggregates

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

does anyone know how to sum and subtract from aggregate values of a group? I have Groups 1,2, and 3 with Amounts. I want to take the sum of Group 1 and subtract it by the sum of Group 2 in a row outside the main row grouping. I've used IF statements and looked all over as well as tested everything i can think of. Can anyone shed light how to do this?

DataSet1
Fields: "Group", "Amounts"

Note: SQL is not an option because i have a column grouping across the top as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "outside the main row grouping." Could you provide an example?

From your description (less the one hedge factor I just mentioned), it looks like all you need to do is this:

```
select <whatever>, Sum( Field1 ) as Group1, Sum( Field2 ) as Group2,
       Sum( Field1 ) - Sum( Field2 ) as FinalAmount
from   ...
```

Edit: So you have an actual column called "Group" and you want sums of each group designated by the value of that column. That's easy to do.

```
select Group,
       Sum( case Group when 1 then Amount else 0 end ) as Group1,
       Sum( case Group when 2 then Amount else 0 end ) as Group2,
       Sum( case Group when 3 then Amount else 0 end ) as Group3
from   ...
```

If you want to do further processing between the group totals, I would suggest CTE or derived/inline view.

Comment: Hey Tom thanks!I have two fields "Group" and "amount". There is either a 1,2, or 3 value in the "Group" field. I'm trying to group on 1,2, or 3 then get the total "amount" per each grouping. There is a 3rd field that i didn't mention that is grouped across the columns called "CODE". "CODE" is for multiple projects during a period. Because of "CODE" i think changing my sql view is not an option so its report builder. So i have a grouping on Group in my tablix. I entered a regular text cell outside this group for a calc.  =(SUM(Fields!AMOUNT.Value),Fields!GROUP.Value=1, "DataSet1") Doesn't work.